# Paypal express check out details

Tags: paypal

I am new using express checkout, until now I was using the old button but since the ipn simulator does not seem to work I decided to change method.
I am trying to execute the payment and update the DB after that.

Until here everything is ok:

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
  return actions.payment.execute().then(function(response) {
  window.alert('Payment Complete!\r\n' + data.returnUrl + ' --- '+ data.payerID + ' --- ' + data.paymentID + ' --- '+ data.paymentToken + ' --- ');
  });
}
```

now, how do I get at least the user email to update the db???
Is it possible to do that right in the onAuthorise, may be with a simple ajax or jquery request without complicate the life?
I read that if you call a method called something like 'getexpresscheckoutdetails' with the data.paymentID as a paramether you get everything back but I can figure out how exactly.

I would like to have something like this at hte end:

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
  return actions.payment.execute().then(function(response) {

  Jquery.request_or_whatever_do_it("myweb.com/update_db.php?" + data.paymentID);
  window.location("the same page where the payment started but with new values on it");

  });
}
```

1000 Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
return actions.payment.execute().then(function(response) {
```

Take a look in that `response` variable. All of the details should be there.